# How to read continuously connected bluetooth device?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am trying to connect my App to the bluetooth device and after that i am doing the functionality Read and Write. I am able to do connectivity and Write command to device. But i am not able to do Read functionality.

The "Read" functionality is like, as soon as device socket will get connect to the App, it should send the device information continuously. But i my case, read() method is calling but every time i am getting the length on InputStream in 0.

Below is the code what i am writing. Please check it where i am going wrong and please help me.

```
public class ConnectionThread implements Runnable {

    private static final String CLASSTAG = ConnectionThread.class.getSimpleName();
    public static BluetoothSocket mSocket;

    private InputStream inStream;
    private OutputStream outStream;
    private boolean canceled = false;
    private Context mContext;

    public ConnectionThread(Context context, BluetoothDevice device) {
        this.mContext = context;
        try {
            mSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(Constants.mUUID));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(CLASSTAG, "createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", e);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void run() {

        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        if(BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().isDiscovering()) {
            BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
        }

        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(CLASSTAG, "connect failed", e);
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            disconnect();
            return;
        }

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            inStream = mSocket.getInputStream();
            outStream = mSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(CLASSTAG, "IO streams init failed", e);
            disconnect();
            return;
        }

        while (!canceled) {
            read();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(CLASSTAG, "sleep failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void applyCommand(String configCommand) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = null;
        bytes = new BigInteger(configCommand,16).toByteArray();
        if (mSocket.isConnected()) {
            //write(bytes);
            outStream.write(bytes);
            Log.d(CLASSTAG, "Command apply: " + bytes + " (" + configCommand + ")");
        }
        Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.cmd_updated), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void read() {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[128];

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        try {
            // Read from the InputStream
            if (inStream.available() > 0) {
                int bytes = inStream.read(buffer);
                if (bytes > 0) {
                    Log.d(CLASSTAG, "Response: " + new String(buffer, 0, bytes));
                }
            }
            // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
            // mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(CLASSTAG, "reading from input stream failed", e);
            disconnect();
        }
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        try {
            if (outStream != null) {
                outStream.close();
            }
            if (inStream != null) {
                inStream.close();
            }
            mSocket.close();
            canceled = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(CLASSTAG, "close socket", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to read and write from different threads!

Comment: So, for read again i need to connect the socket with another thread?

Comment: yeah,i was reading and writing from the communication port over bluetooth to aurdino,i was handling the read and write in different threads,also you need to use Synchornise where you are reading or writing so that you dont arrive at any dead lock condition